# Wordpress redirecting a https non trailing slash to a non https trailing slash

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

My Wordpress is redirecting (301) a non trailing slash path to the trailing slash one. But the problem is that this redirection is loosing the httpS protocol.

take a look at the httpstatus.io

[image]

The server is hosted on AWS with CloudFront CDN on it.

Who does the http->https is the cloudfront and and the trailing comma to the non trailing comma is the server.

How can I redirect it propperly?

Here is the .htaccess from wodpress

```
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
```

and here is the 'non sensitive' part of wp-config

```
define('DOMAIN',$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] );
define('WP_HOME',"https://".DOMAIN."/blog/");
define('WP_SITEURL',"https://".DOMAIN."/blog/");
define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', false);
$_SERVER['HTTPS'] = 'on';
```

Comment: The backend is returning http link in the location.
curl -vko /dev/null https://lavembebe.com.br/blog
 HTTP/2 301 
< content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
< content-length: 237
< location: http://lavembebe.com.br/blog/
< date: Sun, 19 May 2019 05:15:42 GMT
< server: Apache
< x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
< age: 26956
< x-cache: Hit from cloudfront
< via: 1.1 5be3f7f1116b2bdf516cbdf031058b04.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
< x-amz-cf-id: QX1Vvman0mQKLnHDhL1_juAe31DgaWZEpiyhicSX-WGB-i0fMHFGOQ==

Comment: but when trying https://lavembebe.com.br/blog/, backend doesn't redirect, possible backend misconfiguration, I don't know what :(